# MVVM How and where to 'Get Item By Id'

Tags: c#, mvvm

I want to abstract data access from my model.  I have classes that have collections of other objects and also primary item of object by id.

I need a static GetItemById call from the model for adding these items from the model *abstracted* from any data access.

How does one go about it?

*FYI I'm currently building the model.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me like a use for the repository pattern
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx
(this is a sharepoint example but you can easily find info on general repository patterns in DDD literature)